# listbox items to ms access first item is repeated vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, listbox

I am trying to get the items from a listbox (19 in all) transferred to a MS Access database

the following code

```
        For i = 0 To Me.lstResourceTypes.Items.Count - 1
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResourceType", lstResourceTypes.Items(i).ToString)
            MsgBox(lstResourceTypes.Items(i).ToString)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
```

creates 19 records in the Access table, but each record is filled with the first item from the listbox.

The messagebox does show that the code loops through the listbox, so why does it not reflect this in the access table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you continuosly add a new parameter to the collection at each loop. The method doesn't replace a previous parameter with the same ParameterName. So, only the first one is used by the query.
You need to clear the parameters inside the loop

```
    For i = 0 To Me.lstResourceTypes.Items.Count - 1
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResourceType", lstResourceTypes.Items(i).ToString)
        MsgBox(lstResourceTypes.Items(i).ToString)
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        command.Parameters.Clear()
    Next
```

but a more correct way to do this task is to define the parameter outside the loop and change only the parameter value inside the loop.
So assuming that the parameter is referring to a string type column you could write

```
    command.Parameters.Add("@ResourceType", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    For i = 0 To Me.lstResourceTypes.Items.Count - 1
        command.Parameters("@ResourceType").Value = lstResourceTypes.Items(i).ToString
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
```

Notice that I use Add and not AddWithValue. The second one has numerous drawbacks as explained here: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @svenliegeois, if this answer solves your problem, please accept it so everyone knows that you don't need any more help. You are not supposed to post comments saying "thanks". Accepting an answer is all the thanks needed and allowed.